# number of $10$-tuples $(a_1,\cdots, a_{10}) $ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{1}{a_i} = 1.$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Let $N_{10}$ be the number of $10$-tuples $(a_1,\cdots, a_{10}), a_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$. Determine whether $N_{10}$ is even or odd.

I think it might be useful to consider for a fixed tuple $(a_1,\cdots, a_{10})$ how many distinct values it has. Suppose there are $s$ distinct values. Then we can let $m_i$ be the number of occurrences of the $i$th smallest distinct value. There are $\frac{n!}{m_1!\cdots m_s!}$ ways to rearrange the tuples. So to determine whether the number is even or odd, it suffices to consider the number of possible tuples where $\frac{n!}{m_1!\cdots m_s!}$ is odd, since if the value is even, it will not change the parity of $N_{10}.$ But how does one find this number? I know that $2,8,10$ are the only positive values $m$ so that ${10\choose m}$ is odd, but how does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily generalize Kummer's theorem to multinomial coefficients.

You get that the values $m_1,m_2,\dots, m_s$ need to have the same $1$ bits in binary as $10_{10}$ without repeating. Notice that this number is $1010$ so there are only two possibilites:

- $s=2$ with $m_1=2$ and $m_2=8$
- $s=1$ with $m_1=10$

In the first case we must have $\frac{2}{a} + \frac{8}{b} = 1$ which is equivalent to $ab -8a-2b = 0$ which is equivalent to $(a-2)(b-8) = 16$

So the solutions $(a,b)$ can be found by iterating through the divisors of $16$. We get: $(3,24),(4,16),(6,12),(10,10),(18,9)$, Of course the solution $(10,10)$ is not really of this kind. So we have $4$ solutions.

For the second case we  clearly have only one solution.

Anyway, we deduce the number of solutins is odd.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the solution a lot better now!